# Can't save credentials in Remote Desktop connection file

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

I have a saved .RDP file for a connection to another computer, if I check the box to "Remember my credentials" the connection attempt is immediately rejected and the authentication box pops back up immediately. I also can't save the credentials in Remote Desktop Connection "Edit" mode.

I had read that the credential saving is impacted by your computer being joined to a domain or not, as well as some group policy settings that control various aspects of stored credentials. I opened the Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Credentials Delegation policy and saw that all the policy elements were set as "Not configured". I changed all of them that had NTLM-only as well as the "Allow Delegating Saved Credentials" policies to enabled and added an entry to the servers list of TERMSRV/* for each.

[image: authentication prompt]

[image: group policy]

Is there something else I may have missed? I did a `gpudate /force` after changing the policy, as well as a courtesy reboot to see if it made any difference. There is nothing in the domain group policy that is forcing these options (that I could find anyway).

Disclaimer: this computer has Sophos SafeGuard 5.5 installed which takes over / augments a lot of the default authentication prompts. It could very well be part of the Sophos virus that is ignoring the policy or has a separate configuration.

Comment: Credential delegation provides a way to bypass password prompts altogether, but shouldn't affect whether you may save a password. Have you checked your password vault to see whether a password was already entered for that end point?